# Storing database changes in Symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony

I have a site where customer service personnel can create, update, and delete various records. I also have a table to store information about changes to the other tables. Is there an automated way I could ensure this storage script always gets run or do I need to drop a persist call in after every update, create, and delete? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I ended out having to write my own logging using LifeCycle callbacks. Pazi's answer is really cool though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could be interested in the [Loggable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md) behaviour of the Doctrine Extensions. For Symfony it's implemented in the [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst).

Autonomous logging and more tested and reliable as own solutions ;)